# Meteor - How to have a method throw an error without dumping to console?

Tags: meteor

When defining a Meteor method, how do I return an error without dumping it to the web console? In other words:

```
Meteor.methods
  myMethod: ->
    # Code...
    if goodThing
      return objData
    else
      throw new Meteor.Error 'my-error', 'Something bad went down.'
```

I want the callback to have an `error` object I can reference, but I don't want the stacktrace dumped to the console, for security reasons.

Comment: A stack trace on the client should never result in a risk of security. If it does, you've done something else wrong.

Comment: Exposure of filenames and line numbers isn't risky?

Comment: No. If they have any use of that (which I doubt), they've already hacked your app.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack The expected behaviour of throwing a `Meteor.Error` is exactly what you want. Nothing is dumped onto the server console and the callback has the error object containing the reason you provide without a stack trace on the client. The code you have provided should work as you expect it to. Unless i'm confused about what you're asking?